# What does the "set 2D pose" function in rviz modfiy to change the pose?

Tags: ros, rviz, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How does "set 2D pose" button in rviz work? When you set a pose using it the pose of the robot will stay on that. What is it changing to do that?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266206/what-does-the-%22set-2d-pose%22-function-in-rviz-modfiy-to-change-the-pose?/) by [j1337](https://answers.ros.org/users/30696/j1337/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ will publish the pose on the 'initialpose' topic. Then your location node (perhaps AMCL) will know how to start the locating. Echo that topic in a terminal and then click the set button. You'll see the message get sent.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2017-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2